# How can I check if the day is Valentine’s Day every year?

Tags: solidity, timestamp, time

Happy Valentine’s Day fellow nerds! This year for Valentine’s Day I want to mint my gf a valentine NFT. Since I’m building it I want to turn it into an NFT project that is free to mint for the public on Valentine’s Day only.

I’m trying to figure out how to do this using UNIX time but can’t think of a good solution without modelling the calendar year and leap years and such into my calculations.

Any libraries or solutions to check the following condition? ‘’’if (monthOf(timestamp) == 2 && dayOf(timestamp) == 14) mintValentine(msg.sender);’’’

Answer (score 2):

I know about this library here: https://github.com/bokkypoobah/BokkyPooBahsDateTimeLibrary

There are instructions in the README. In any case it's very simple, you can just copy the library into your contract and use the `timestampToDate(block.timestamp)` function to get the current day and month.